# Help with enabling USB Debugging

Tags: usb-debugging

My problem is that I need to enable USB Debugging on my Asus me301t. When I go to try and enable it in settings, all developer options are grayed out and I can't enable it using the slider at the top of the screen. I'm using Android JellyBean 4.2.1. Help?

Comment: What happens when you click on the slider to enable developer options?

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all

Comment: @ekko add a picture so we can see.

Comment: Is it possible that that portion of the screen (hardware) does not respond to touch? Or is it for that Developer Options screen (software) only?

Comment: Do you have any enterprise/work policies applied to you phone ? We used to disable it for many of our users.

Comment: @Dukes It does have enterprise/work policies on it. There is a bunch of limitations that were put on it in regard to chaning settings; so I have very limited access to changing settings.

Comment: @easycheese heres a screenshot https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/592x370q90/822/0r7m.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If you have an enterprise device then it is likely disabled by your IT department to prevent unknown users from accessing the data on the phone. If you need access then you will have to go to the policy administrator to get it unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Double Power tablet I bought for my kids running Android version 4.4.2.  Considering @jeffchang comment, I tried simply rotating the tablet from landscape to portrait orientation.  The slider to turn on/off developer options now works perfectly - but only when the tablet is in portrait orientation, it does not work in landscape - strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting a different USB cable or may be restarting a device might help too.

Comment: If all the developer options are greyed out, not just USB debugging, then it's clearly not a USB problem. Changing the USB cable won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable the Developer option manually. For this you have to go Settings -> About Phone, then tap on the build number 7 times.

Hope that will help :-)
Thanks

Comment: I already have access to developer options. The slider to enable it is grayed out along with all the options

Comment: As the OP already stated in his question: *all developer options are grayed out* – so obviously he doesn't need to "enable the Developer option manually" by tapping the build number.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Samsung GT s7392  Android 4.1.2.
All common issues like slider, tapping build number, were not relevant as they were fine.

Finally found out that it was because of the Worx software by Citrix which had been installed. This had taken away the option to do USB Debugging. Once I uninstalled Worx, the button got miraculously "ungreyed".

Uninstalling Worx is also a bit tricky. Follow the steps [outlined here](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xmob-dm-85/xmob-android-user-enroll-unenrolldevice-tsk.html):

> **To unenroll your Android device from Device Manager**
>
> Updated: 2013-06-16
>
> 1. Open the Control app, tap the Menu key on your phone and then tap Settings.
> 2. Tap Personal, tap Security and then tap Device Administrators.
> 3. Clear the Connect check box.
> 4. In the Device Administrator dialog box, tap to select Deactivate and then tap OK.
> 5. In Settings, tap Application Manager.
> 6. Select the Worx Home, tap Uninstall and then tap OK

.